# Convert registration-based service to Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have an external service with a simple API, based on registration :

- `API.listen(listener)` will register the listener to receive updates whenever they come in
- `API.stopListening(listener)` will remove the listener, which will no longer receive updates

I believe that a Kotlin Shared-Flow would be a good representation, and more convenient to work with, so I'm trying to bridge the two apis.

However, I can't figure out when / how to remove the listener when the flow should be stopped.

```kotlin
fun API.toFlow(): SharedFlow<Int> {
  val flow = MutableSharedFlow(replay = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
  val listener = Listener { newValue -> flow.tryEmit(newValue) }
  this.listen(listener)
  // TODO: remove listener at some point
  return flow
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated flow builder for exactly this kind of scenario, the `callbackFlow`:

```
fun API.toFlow() = callbackFlow {
    val listener = Listener { newValue -> trySendBlocking(newValue) }
    this@toFlow.listen(listener)

    awaitClose { stopListening(listener) }
}
//.shareIn(...)
//.stateIn(...)
```

Inside the lambda you define and register the listener. For each value that should be emitted to the flow, you need to call one of the `send` functions (or `trySend`, or `trySendBlocking`, depending on your needs for error handling).

When the flow is done (after calling `cancel` or `close` inside the builder block, or the collecting coroutine is cancelled), the block of `awaitClose` is called. This can be used to clean up after you are done listening, like unregistering the listener.

This flow builder creates a *cold* flow, meaning that every time the flow is collected, the builder block is executed again (even if `API.toFlow()` was called only once). If you want to share this flow for multiple collectors, you can convert it to a `SharedFlow` by calling `shareIn`. The configuration of the flow from your example looks a lot like a `StateFlow`, though, so you can directly call `stateIn` instead of `shareIn`.

Regarding the comment about stopping a flow made *hot* by calling `shareIn` or `stateIn`, let's take a look at what actually goes on when a flow generated by a `callbackFlow` is collected.

Let's assume we created a `StateFlow` (compared to a generic `SharedFlow` it will implicitly have `replay = 1` and `onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST` with an additional `distinctUntilChanged()`) with this:

```
.stateIn(
    scope = flowScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    initialValue = initial,
)
```

Now, we need a value for `flowScope` which will be the `CoroutinesScope` that should be used to run the flow. It is needed because the flow is now *hot* and it will run even when there is no one to collect it (not needed for *cold* flows since the collecting coroutine scope is used for that).

In addition, we need an `initial` value that instantly provides a value for the flow. A `StateFlow` always has a value, even when the underlying flow (here the `callbackFlow`) hasn't yet emitted a new value.

These two values can be provided as a parameter to the `API.toFlow()` function, for example.

Regarding your question, the parameter `started` is the most interesting, though: It defines how the underlying flow is started. With `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()` the underlying flow starts when there is at least one collector subscribed to the `StateFlow`. The flow is being stopped when the last collector unsubscribed.

For the `callbackFlow` that means that the builder block is executed every time when a collector subscribes to the `StateFlow` and is the only one doing so. Every subsequent subscribers will receive the same values the first subscriber receives. This way collectors can subscribe and unscubscribe from the `StateFlow`, the `callbackFlow` will only notice the first one.

Only when the last collector unsubscribed, the `callbackFlow` is notices that it should be closed. In that case the `awaitClose` close lambda is executed und the flow is completed.

The `StateFlow`, however, is still active (`StateFlow`s never complete). Should a new collector subscribe to the flow, the underlying flow is restarted. For our `callbackFlow` that means that the builder block is executed again and a new flow (with a new listener) is created.

As I understood, this is your desired behavior, and `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()` provides this out-of-the-box. There are other `SharingStarted` behaviors, though.

One final note: If you frequently add and remove subscribers to your `StateFlow` you may run into the situation where the underlying `callbackFlow` is repeatedly stopped and restarted, which may be costly depending on how your `Listener` works. In that case you can specify a time period as an optional parameter to `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()` for that the underlying flow is kept alive even after the last collector unsubscribed. If in that time period a new collector subscribes, the `StateFlow` resumes as though nothing happened and the underlying `callbackFlow` never gets stopped and restarted.
A common value would be 5000 milliseconds, but you can put there anything that fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks :) I've seen `callbackFlow` but I stuck to the fact that it was a cold flow. If I use `shareIn()`, how can I stop the flow and unregister ?

Comment: I've amended the answer by an explanation why a properly configured `StateFlow` does this automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, it makes more sense now. However, I don't think `WhileSubscribed` suits my needs, as I also need to access the latest value through `StateFlow.value` (or via `SharedFlow.replayCache`), which will not be updated if there are no listener. `Eagerly` is fine for my purpose.
As I understand, I can however call `flowScope.cancel()`, and that will terminate the flow and call the block in `awaitClose`. Is that correct ?

Comment: That's true, cancelling that scope will also stop the underlying flow. The `StateFlow`as well, obviously, since there the coroutine scope that was running it is now gone.